# file Stream to s3 file upload using lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, box-api

I am working on AWS with box api. I want to upload the file to s3 bucket using the lambda function. but giving the errors

I am using this api https://developer.box.com/en/reference/get-files-id-content/ to get the content of the file and upload to s3 bucket. But contents are in stream.

Below is my code

```
 let status= await  appUserClient.files.getReadStream(fileId, null, async function(error, stream) {
     var params = {Bucket: 'bucketname', Key: 'key.csv', Body: stream};
      let status= await s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            return 0;
          }else{
               console.log(data);
              return 1;
          }
      }).promise();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

You need

```
const stream = require('stream');



   function uploadFromStream(s3) {
     var pass = new stream.PassThrough();

     var params = {Bucket: BUCKET, Key: KEY, Body: pass};
     s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
        console.log(err, data);
     });

     return pass;
}
```

Now you can use it

```
appUserClient.files.getReadStream(fileId, null,function(error, stream){

    if(error){
       console.log(error)
      }
    else{
      stream.pipe(uploadFromStream(s3))
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your connect! but giving the error stream is undefined

Comment: you did not get stream while getReadStream??

Comment: var pass = new stream.PassThrough(); this line giving the error

Comment: ooh ok `const stream = require('stream');` you need this..update the answer